# AddRange causing contents of list to be changed

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am having an issue with add range it appears to be overwritten my second item in my list I am using the add range method

For Example

My orders talbe has 4 fields in it it gets added to my list fine

On second pass 
My next table get added to list but is showing more fields than should be and the list is full of the second table the first one is overwirtten  I believe this may be the issue here

> ```
>   _newPersistantObjectList.First().FieldsList.AddRange(_newFieldList);
> ```

```
private void genXmlSchema_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<TableDefnition> _fieldNameList = new List<TableDefnition>();
        PersistentObject _testObjects = new PersistentObject();
        List<GridViewRowInfo> _checkRows = GetCheckedRows(rgTableNames);
        List<PersistentObject> _fieldScehmasList = new List<PersistentObject>();
        _newPersistantObjectList = new List<PersistentObject>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in _checkRows)
        {
            i++;

            var currentRow = (TableNames)row.DataBoundItem;
            rgFieldsOfTable.DataSource = db.GetALLTableDeiniations(currentRow.TABLE_NAME);
            _fieldNameList.AddRange(db.GetALLTableDeiniations(currentRow.TABLE_NAME));                
            _fieldScehmasList.AddRange(BuildSchema(_fieldNameList, currentRow.TABLE_NAME));
        }

        _newPObject.PersistentObjects.AddRange(_fieldScehmasList);
        _newPObject.ClassPrefix = "Persistent";
        _newPObject.ClassSuffix = "";
        _newPObject.Language = "VB";
        _newPObject.Path = @"C:\Sage200SchemaExtensions";
        _newPObject.GenerateSeparateFiles = "false";
        _newPObject.GenerateBusinessObjects = "false";
        _newPObject.BaselineSchema = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage 200 SDK\SageObjectStore.xml";
        _newPObject.DataTypes = "";
        _newPObject.Enumerations = "";
        _newPObject.MemberVariablePrefix = "_";
        _newPObject.ApplicationNamespace = "BusinessObjects";
        schemeContent.Text = HelperXml.ToXML(_newPObject);
    }
```

Build schema is what i use to collect the information on the fields in the table.

```
    public List<PersistentObject> BuildSchema(List<TableDefnition> fieldList, string tableName)
    {
        _newPersistantObjectList.Clear();
        _newFieldList.Clear();
        _newObject.Name = tableName;
        foreach (var item in fieldList.Where(w=>w.TableName ==tableName).ToList())
        {

            FieldSchemaXml _newSchema = new FieldSchemaXml();


            _newSchema = ConvertSQLDataTypeToSage(item.Type, _newSchema, item);


            _newSchema.Name = item.Field;
            _newSchema.IsUnique = "false";
            _newSchema.IsReadOnly = "false";
            _newSchema.IsQueryable = "true";
            if (item.is_nullable == 1)
            {

                _newSchema.IsNullable = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                _newSchema.IsNullable = "false";
            }

            _newSchema.IsReadOnly = "false";
            _newSchema.IsUnique = "false";
            _newSchema.Group = "false";

            _newSchema.IsLockable = "false";
            _newSchema.IsDeltaField = "false";
            _newSchema.AllowOverwrite = "True";
            _newSchema.IsPrimaryKey = "false";
            _newSchema.Scale = "0";
            _newSchema.IsIndexed = "false";
            _newSchema.FillType = "None";
            _newSchema.Direction = "Input";
            _newSchema.OverrideFormatting = "false";
            _newSchema.ValueSetByDatabase = "false";
            _newSchema.FormatScale = "0";
            _newSchema.NegativeFormatting = "Standard";
            _newSchema.AggregateFunction = "None";
            _newSchema.ValueSetByDatabase = "false";
            _newSchema.IsExcludedFromCopy = "false";
            _newSchema.FriendlyName = "";

            _newSchema.IsTransient = "false";
            _newSchema.IsExpression = "false";
            _newSchema.IsBrowsable = "true";
            _newSchema.IsQueryable = "true";
            _newSchema.IsEnumeration = "false";
            _newSchema.IsAddInPrimaryKey = "false";
            _newSchema.IsExcludedFromReset = "false";
            _newSchema.IsMember = "false";
            _newSchema.AddInTableName = "";


            _newObject.IsCacheable = "false";

            _newObject.Description = "";


            _newObject.AllowZeroKeys = "false";
            _newObject.TransactionMode = "Required";
            _newObject.IsStoredProcedure = "false";
            _newObject.ProcedureReturnType = "";
            _newObject.AlwaysAllowPaging = "false";
            _newObject.Namespace = "";
            _newObject.Name = tableName;
            _newObject.PagingFields = "";

            _newFieldList.Add(_newSchema);

        }
        _newPersistantObjectList.Add(_newObject);
        _newPersistantObjectList.First().FieldsList.AddRange(_newFieldList);

        return _newPersistantObjectList;

    }
```

This is my schema

```
public class SageXmlDefiniation
{

    [XmlRoot("ObjectStore", Namespace = "urn:SageObjectStore")]

     public class ObjectStore

        {
        [XmlIgnore]
        private  List<PersistentObject> _PersistentObject = new List<PersistentObject>();

        public string ApplicationNamespace { get; set; }
        public string MemberVariablePrefix { get; set; }
        public string ClassPrefix { get; set; }
        public string ClassSuffix { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string GenerateBusinessObjects { get; set; }
        public string GenerateSeparateFiles { get; set; }

        public string NameSpace { get; set; }

        public List<PersistentObject> PersistentObjects
        {
            get { return _PersistentObject; }
            set { _PersistentObject = value; }
        }
        public string DataTypes
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Enumerations { get; set; }

        public string BaselineSchema { get; set; }



}
public class PersistentObject
    {
        private List<FieldSchemaXml> _Fields = new List<FieldSchemaXml>();

        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("Fields")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field")]
        public List<FieldSchemaXml> FieldsList
        {
            get { return _Fields; }
            set { _Fields = value; }
        }
        public string IsCacheable { get; set; }
        public string AllowZeroKeys { get; set; }
        public string AlwaysAllowPaging { get; set; }
        public string Namespace { get; set; }
        public string PagingFields { get; set; }
        public string TransactionMode { get; set; }
        public string IsStoredProcedure { get; set; }
        public string ProcedureReturnType { get; set; }



    }
    public class FieldSchemaXml
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string DbType { get; set; }
        public string Precision { get; set; }
        public string Scale { get; set; }
        public string FillType { get; set; }
        public string IsNullable { get; set; }
        public string IsReadOnly { get; set; }
        public string AllowOverwrite { get; set; }
        public string IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }

        public string IsDeltaField { get; set; }
        public string IsIndexed { get; set; }
        public string IsTransient { get; set; }
        public string IsUnique { get; set; }

        public string OverrideFormatting { get; set; }
        public string IsLockable { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public string ValueSetByDatabase { get; set; }
        public string FormatScale { get; set; }
        public string FormatMask { get; set; }
        public string NegativeFormatting { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string AggregateFunction { get; set; }
        public string IsExcludedFromCopy { get; set; }
        public string IsExpression { get; set; }
        public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
        public string IsBrowsable { get; set; }
        public string IsQueryable { get; set; }
        public string IsEnumeration { get; set; }

        public string IsAddInPrimaryKey { get; set; }
        public string AddInTableName { get; set; }
        public string AddInRelationField { get; set; }
        public string IsMember { get; set; }
        public string IsExcludedFromReset { get; set; }

    }

 }
```

I have created a small jinq video for you to see the issue.

https://www.screencast.com/t/iJIBzVo7hKNc

Comment: Can you describe further the issue, maybe copy/paste the error text. Please check this meta question : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @Fourat I not getting an error as such their should be 2 distinct elements in the list but the add range is overitting both of them with the same data.

Comment: Please edit your question and specify further the problem you're having.

Comment: @Fourat it clearly explains it above duplication

Comment: You suspect that calling `AddRange` on the `First()` item in the list might be the problem.... so have you tried not doing that? I.e., should the new field list be added to the object you just added instead? Also, this question would benefit greatly from a [mcve].